# Why is my canvas text perfectly fine in one server and separated more on another server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, discord

This code I wrote for my bot works perfectly fine using my testing bot through my local computer on one Discord server. When I upload the code to the official bot server and test it on a different Discord server, the Exp text goes off the canvas and it looks like the characters are more spread out. I'm not sure why it's doing that. Is it a code thing or a server thing or what?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Canvas = require('canvas');

const levels = require('../../levels.json');
const colors = require('../../colors.json');



module.exports = {
    name: 'rank',
    description: 'Displays the level and exp amount',
    async execute(message, args) {

        const levelText = (canvas, text) => {
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        
            let fontSize = 70;
        
            do {
                ctx.font = `${fontSize -= 10}px sans-serif`;
            } while (ctx.measureText(text).width > canvas.width - 300);
        
            return ctx.font;
        };
        
        const expText = (canvas, text) => {
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        
            let fontSize = 90;
        
            do {
                ctx.font = `${fontSize -= 10}px sans-serif`;
            } while (ctx.measureText(text).width > canvas.width - 300);
        
            return ctx.font;
        };

        const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./LevelBackground.png');
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx.strokeStyle = '#74037b';
        ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
            ctx.font = levelText(canvas, levels[message.author.id].level);
            ctx.fillStyle = colors.white;
            ctx.fillText(`Level: ${levels[message.author.id].level}`, canvas.width / 2.7, canvas.height / 3.5);

            ctx.font = expText(canvas, levels[message.author.id].exp);
            ctx.fillStyle = colors.white;
            ctx.fillText(`Exp: ${levels[message.author.id].exp}`, canvas.width / 2.7, canvas.height / 1.1);

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(125, 125, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.clip();

            const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(message.member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'jpg' }));
            ctx.drawImage(avatar, 25, 25, 200, 200);

            const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'levelImage.png');

            return message.channel.send(attachment);
        } else {
            ctx.font = levelText(canvas, levels[message.author.id].level);
            ctx.fillStyle = colors.white;
            ctx.fillText(`Level: ${levels[message.mentions.users.first().id].level}`, canvas.width / 2.7, canvas.height / 3.5);

            ctx.font = expText(canvas, levels[message.mentions.users.first().id].exp);
            ctx.fillStyle = colors.white;
            ctx.fillText(`Exp: ${levels[message.mentions.users.first().id].exp}`, canvas.width / 2.7, canvas.height / 1.1);

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(125, 125, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.clip();

            const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(message.mentions.users.first().displayAvatarURL({ format: 'jpg' }));
            ctx.drawImage(avatar, 25, 25, 200, 200);

            const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'levelImage.png');

            return message.channel.send(attachment);
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: How can you be sure it's not a rendering issue on the client?

Comment: Because I have them side by side in the same server and the testing bot is the way it should be and the official bot is off the side and more spread out both on pc and mobile

Comment: Probably because they don't have the same default `sans-serif` font. Use a web font instead if you need the same result on different systems.

Comment: I changed it to Times New Roman and the font changed but it's still off the edge of the canvas.